# argument list syntax in powershell command (start-process)

Tags: powershell

we want to send parameters in powershell and fail on the syntax.
can you please help.

```
Start-Process -FilePath powershell -Credential $Cred -ArgumentList "Start-Process -Verb RunAs -Wait -FilePath `"$arg3"` -ArgumentList '`"$arg2"` `"$arg4"` `"$arg6"`'"
```

Thanks !!

Comment: If the above is exactly as you are running it then it's becuase you are not escaping the inner double quotes which will be closing the quotes for the `-ArgumentList` args.

Try this:

`Start-Process -FilePath powershell -Credential $Cred -ArgumentList "Start-Process -Verb RunAs -Wait -FilePath \"$arg3\" -ArgumentList '\"$arg2\" \"$arg4\" \"$arg6\"'"`

Comment: Oh after reading my comment I just noticed that you also have a further `-ArgumentList` inside the `-ArgumentList`, is this intended?

Comment: yes. it's a nested start-process. thanks

Comment: Try this. I think your problem is from all of the double quotes. Start-Process -FilePath powershell -Credential $Cred -ArgumentList "Start-Process -Verb RunAs -Wait -FilePath '$arg3' -ArgumentList '$arg2' '$arg4' '$arg6'"

Answer (score 0):

1. Read `PowerShell -Help` for `PowerShell.exe` valid arguments.
2. Note that *inner* double quotes are *doubled* for every level of immersion/embedding.

```
Start-Process -FilePath powershell -Credential $Cred -ArgumentList '-Command', "& {Start-Process -Wait -Verb RunAs -FilePath '""$arg3""' -ArgumentList '""""""""$arg2"""""""" """"""""$arg4"""""""" """"""""$arg6""""""""'}"
```

Tested *without* the `-Credential` parameter as follows:

```
$arg3 = 'D:\bat\CLIParser Pause.exe'
$arg2='au ua'
$arg4='bu ub'
$arg6='cu uc'
Start-Process -FilePath powershell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile', '-Command', "& {Start-Process -Wait -Verb RunAs -FilePath '""$arg3""' -ArgumentList '""""""""$arg2"""""""" """"""""$arg4"""""""" """"""""$arg6""""""""'}"

<# or 
Start-Process -FilePath powershell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile', '-Command', "& {Start-Process -Wait -Verb RunAs -FilePath '""$arg3""' -ArgumentList '""""""""$arg2"""""""" """"""""$arg4"""""""" """"""""$arg6""""""""'}"
<##>

<# or 
Start-Process -FilePath powershell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile', '-Command', "& {Start-Process -Wait -Verb RunAs -FilePath """"""$arg3"""""" -ArgumentList '""""""""$arg2"""""""" """"""""$arg4"""""""" """"""""$arg6""""""""'}"
<##>
```

**Result**:

[image: result]

Here the `CLIParser Pause.exe` is following simple console utility (I wrote in `C++` long ago for testing purposes):

```
// CliParserPause.cpp : parses supplied parameters
// (Windows console application, Visual Studio 2013)

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <wchar.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        wprintf(L"param %d = %S\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    wprintf(L"press any key to continue...");
    std::getchar();
    exit(-999 - argc);  /* exitcode to OS = ( -1000 -supplied_paramaters_count ) */
    return 0;
}
```